# Clustered Standard Errors for Interaction term with plm and coeftest in R

Tags: r, panel, hierarchical-data, plm

I have a dataset with a hierarchical structure with multiple observations on *individuals* over *time* and individuals belonging to *groups*. I run a model with individual and time fixed effects but want to estimate cluster-robust standard errors on the group level.

I use `plm::plm` for the model estimation and `lmtest::coeftest` with `sandwich::vcovCL` for the standard errors:

```
coeftest(Model, vcov = vcovCL(Model, cluster = ~group))
```

When I add interactions terms (multiplication of two independent variables) to the model, `coeftest` does not calculate standard errors for those. Does anyone know why? This happens both for variables that are constant/not constant on the group level.

Comment: There is no function `vcovCL` in the package `lmtest` from where you likely use `coeftest`. Did you mean `sandwich::vcovCL`? You are more likely to get a proper answer if you can add a reproducible example.

Comment: Yes you are correct vcovCL comes from sandwich package.